# Angular Ag-Grid: Undo selected row changes on button click

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Application built on Angular and Javascript.

AG-Grid editable records having 1st column as Checkbox.
After making any changes say on 5 records, after selecting checkbox for any particular record, on click of button Say 
`<button name="Undo Changes" (click) = "undoFn()/>"`

Need to undo the changes made, and reload the previous data for that particular records(row) only, not the entire grid.

Button is not inline with all records like a seperate column. There is only 1 button that too **outside the Grid**

Once again in short- **Need To refresh only particular row whose checkbox has been checked, on click of Undo button present outside the Grid**

Not finding solution to this anywhere.

Comment: You may pass `this` in to `undoFn(this)` function and get the data in the `.ts` file and update the data and update the `list` of data shown.

Comment: @BijayYadav - that button is not inline with all records, there is only 1 button that too, outside the Grid.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know you kind of problem. If you operate with a @Input or a property that will be set by a rest-call:

```
@Input() data: Array<YourInterface>;
```

or

```
public data: Array<YourInterface>;

...

public onInit() {
  httpClient.get(configuration).subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data;
  }
}
```

then using this data-property in you template directly is not useful, because, you are not able to determine the state of this data-property, before you modified it via the ui part of your app.

Instead of using it directly, do something like this:

```
public inputData: Array<YourInterface>;
@Input() data: Array<YourInterface>;

...

public onInit() {
  this.inputData = {...this.data};
}
```

or

```
public inputData: Array<YourInterface>;
public data: Array<YourInterface>;

...

public onInit(): void {
  httpClient.get(configuration).subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data;
    this.inputData = {...this.data};
  }
}
```

And use `inputData` in your template, instead of using `data`.

Then add a reset-method, that you can use to reset the data to the state before the manipulation with the ui (connecting this method to the reset button will reset all your rows).

```
resetData(): void {
  this.inputData = {...this.data};
}
```

After that use a method to persist your data.

```
saveData(): void {
  this.data = {...this.inputData};

  ...

  // more steps to persistence
  // make a http.post or emit this.data
}
```

EDIT: I assume, that you get an array of anything, every entry of this array is an object and has a model, to display it as table.

Interface:

```
interface YourInterface {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  tel: string;
}
```

Sample Data:

```
let data: Array<YourInterface> = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'A name',
    tel: '+892383498239'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Another name',
    tel: '+23298238923'
  }
];
```

Comment: Your idea seems correct but one question, how to identify data for particular record/row

Comment: What you meant by `Array<YourInterface>`?

Comment: @Olivia I assume, that you get an Array of anything to display any entry as a row of this Array in a grid. Every entry is an Object and has a Model of the Objects, that you get from the backend or a JSON. If you do not have this Model, use `any`. `Array<any>` or `any[]`.

Comment: yes I am getting an array of object exactly as you mentioned. Let me try it.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple events which ag-Grid provides on cell editing for you to utilize for example: by using **which()** method on the event would tell you that which cell is being targeted and you can create a map of an old value and new value with it. If the button is clicked you can check the rows and accordingly reset the values of the cell.

Comment: Sounds a good idea, is it possible you can present it with an example..?